# CreateInstance doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, object, com, createinstance

I`m currently working on a little program and my programming skills are not the best, but it works already pretty good, except this part.

I managed to start another program from my executable with the appending code. So if I loop through the following code snippet for the first time the program *INCA* will start and I am able to use the programm's API-functions.

But... when *INCA* is closed meanwhile and I run this code again nothing happens and I can't access the API, even if I start *INCA* manually afterwards.

```
    public bool Init()
    {
        var type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID( "Inca.Inca" );

        if ( type == null )
            return false;

        _inca = Activator.CreateInstance( type );

       return _inca != null;
    }
```

What am I missing?? Do I need to reassign or release the com object?

Comment: What for a kind of program is "INCA"? And how do you "close" it?

Comment: It's a calibration tool in the automotive sector. It sometimes crashes and than I can't connect/open it with the above code, although it works only the first time, afterwards I have to restart my program in order to reconnect with INCA again.

Comment: Which functions do you use to open and close the api (after you called the above mentioned `Init()` function)?

Comment: What type of COM object is that? InProc or out of proc? What apartment model?

Comment: Actually I don't really open it afterwards, the above code already starts Inca and I close only my program at the end not explicit the api, especially not when INCA is closed meanwhile.

Comment: I think the type might be "System._ComObject", and I haven't heard about the rest @RemusRusanu

Comment: So you are creating the object with `_inca = Activator.CreateInstance( type );` and a window opens. When you are done you basically close this window and from that point you can't open this window again (until you restart your application).

Comment: I am creating the object with  `_inca = Activator.CreateInstance( type )` and the program (inca) starts, than I'm also able to use the api-functions. Than when somebody closes inca, I am running this code again, but it doesn't start the program again, like it did the first time... Does the object still reference to the old inca instance?

Comment: Is there no method on the `Inca.Inca` class which you can use to "close" the api (something like `_inca.Close();` or `_inca.Dispose();`)?

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It works!!! I thought I don't have to close it because the program was manually closed or crashed before, but closing (the inca tool server) and initializing it again works!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the api before creating a new instance (see comments of the question for details).

```
public bool Init()
{
    if ( _inca != null )
        _inca.Close();
    var type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID( "Inca.Inca" );

    if ( type == null )
        return false;

    _inca = Activator.CreateInstance( type );

    return _inca != null;
 }
```